# Sponsored by a riley riddle

Tags: word-property, letters

What 6 letter word has the same properties?

> The whole makes harm,
>
> 5 letters makes me displeasured,
>
> 4 letters makes me a national greenhouse,
>
> 3 letters, makes me a wooden canvas.
>
> 2 letters is in a medical facility,
>
> Lastly,  for 1 letter, you may wanna request this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The word is

> DANGER which can be something that causes harm

5 letters makes me displeasured

> ANGER when you are displeased

4 letters makes me a national greenhouse

> NGER, or [National Greenhouse and Energy Reporting](http://www.cleanenergyregulator.gov.au/NGER) in Australia

3 letters, makes me a wooden canvas.

> GER is also a Yurt, or a latice-work of wood covered with canvas

2 letters is in a medical facility

> ER or emergency room

Lastly, for 1 letter, you may wanna request this.

> R as in I need some R&R (Rest and Recreation)